# How to delete the first node of doubly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have an implementation of doubly linked list , and I'm trying to delete a particular node at a given position. I managed to delete the second node to the last node but when I try to delete the first node it fails, I wonder what's wrong with my code.

I've already tried this but still doesn't work

```
head.next.previous = null;
head = head.next;
```

> This is my code

```
public class Proses {
    private class Node{
        String Matkul;
        int NilaiUts;
        int NilaiUAS;
        Node previous;  
        Node next;  

        public Node(String Matkul, int Nilai, int NilaiUAS) {
            this.Matkul = Matkul;
            this.NilaiUts = Nilai;
            this.NilaiUAS = NilaiUAS;
        }  
    }  

    Node head, tail = null;    
    public void addNode(String matkul, int Nilai, int NilaiUAS) {   
        Node newNode = new Node(matkul, Nilai, NilaiUAS);   
        if(head == null) {   
            head = tail = newNode;    
            head.previous = null;  
            tail.next = null;  
        } else {  
            tail.next = newNode;   
            newNode.previous = tail;  
            tail = newNode;  
            tail.next = null;  
        }  
    }  

    public void delete(int position){
        if (head == null || n <= 0) 
            return; 
        Node current = head; 
        int i; 
        for (i = 1; current != null && i < position; i++) 
        { 
            current = current.next; 
        } 
        if (current == null) 
            return; 
        deleteNode(head, current); 
    }

    //delete function
    public Node deleteNode(Node head, Node del){
        if (head == null || del == null){
            return null; 
        }
        if (head == del){
            head = del.next;
            del.next.previous = null;
        }
        if (del.next != null){
            del.next.previous = del.previous; 
        }
        if (del.previous != null){
            del.previous.next = del.next; 
        }
        del = null; 
        return head; 
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the `n` in the delete function? are you missing some code?

Comment: oh sorry I changed the n name in the argument with position, I forgot to change it on the loop

Comment: which function you are using to delete the head node? `delete` or `deleteNode`?

Comment: `delete` method is only used to give the position of the node and the `deleteNode` is the function that going to delete the node

Comment: can you also add the node creation and deletion sequence?, functions looks fine to me.

Comment: here's my main class link](https://pastebin.com/9RRxxMUf), the value position is given by `hapus` variable and send to the `delete` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that, head is not getting changed in `deleteNode` function because it's pass by value. Consider the following scenario:

1. You are deleting the position 1. Head is pointing to the node1, so
   it store the address of node1. assume it's 1001.
2. Now you call `deleteNode` function with head reference and currentNode, so head reference is get passed to the function argument as pass by value. so in function   argument `head` contains the address 1001.
3. Now you perform the delete operation, so the function's `head` is changing it's position to the next node. But, your class member's `head` is still pointing to the first position.
4. To overcome this, you can set the `head` again, because you are returning it from the `deleteNode` function. Like:

Change the code as follow

```
public void delete(int position){
        if (head == null || n <= 0) 
            return; 
        Node current = head; 
        int i; 
        for (i = 1; current != null && i < position; i++) 
        { 
            current = current.next; 
        } 
        if (current == null) 
            return; 
        head = deleteNode(head, current); 
    }
```

Comment: Hey Sandeep, isn't the Node object passed as parameter to the deleteNode pass by reference? If I did something like head = head.next in the method (assuming this doen't fail) and I try to print the value pointed by "head" node from main/outside the delete method context, wouldn't it print the value in the next node and not the original "head" node

Comment: If you put `head=head.next` in the `deleteNode` method, when `head` is passed as a argument to the function, then `head` variable is created for this method as a method variable and it will point to the next node. Bu the actual `head` class's member variable is still pointing to the same location. So if you print the `head` outside of the `deleteNode` function, it points at the same location as previous. Considering you are not returning the changed `head` position and setting it again to the `head`.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, if the scenario is such that it ends up with 1 node (head will be pointing to this node) and you want to delete this node (i.e. head), code will fail with NullPointerException at

```
del.next.previous = null;
```

> as del.next is NULL;

Use can take a look at below code to delete a Node from doubly linked list

```
    // Function to delete a node in a Doubly Linked List. 
    // head_ref --> pointer to head node pointer. 
    // del --> data of node to be deleted. 
    void deleteNode(Node head_ref, Node del) 
    { 

        // Base case 
        if (head == null || del == null) { 
            return; 
        } 

        // If node to be deleted is head node 
        if (head == del) { 
            head = del.next; 
        } 

        // Change next only if node to be deleted 
        // is NOT the last node 
        if (del.next != null) { 
            del.next.prev = del.prev; 
        } 

        // Change prev only if node to be deleted 
        // is NOT the first node 
        if (del.prev != null) { 
            del.prev.next = del.next; 
        } 

        // Finally, free the memory occupied by del 
        return; 
    }
```

code ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-a-node-in-a-doubly-linked-list/